# Decoding de arquivo em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, codificação-de-caracteres, sistema-de-arquivos

Tenho um arquivo que está completamente escrito assim após o meu crawler também escrito em Python ter salvo os dados nele:

`b'N\xc3\xa3o n\xc3\xa3o n\xc3\xa3o, n\xc3\xb3s iremos sim!'`

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de eu conseguir tirar o encoding deste arquivo e passar para Unicode o mais rápido o possível! Se possível sem ter de instalar nenhum programa para não atrapalhar na performance do meu crawler e na minha execução deste serviço.

Já tentei utilizar bytes.encode e depois bytes.decode, mas, como era de se esperar, ele volta para o estado inicial, e também percebi que as strings não tem nenhum comando de decoding.

Comment: O seu arquivo em *Python* está com os caracteres especias em hexadecimal `(\xc3\xa3o)`, e vc quer escrevê-los normalmente, é isso?

Comment: Sim @BrumazziDB eu preciso tirar estes caracteres e substituí-los pelas versões unicode deles, só que meu arquivo tem mais de 140 mil linhas assim, então precisava de alguma solução em python!

Comment: Não tem como decodificar o conteúdo desse arquivo, parece que foi escrito dessa maneiro por sacanagem, todo o conteúdo está estruturado para ser usado como string em python, o você terá que ler o arquivo e usar o replace para substituir as sequencias hexadecimais e as aspas – Brumazzi DB 1 hora atrás   editar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O "`b'`"  de prefixo na representação do seu objeto mostra que o texto que você tem nesse ponto do seu programa é um objeto  `bytes`, não uma string de texto.

Em Python 3 as duas coisas são diferentes - já que desde que inventaram codificações multi-byte de texto, não se pode dizer que um byte é um caractére.

O fluxo normal de trabalho em qualquer aplicação em Python é:

1. pegar seus dados de entrada;
2. se a biblioteca uq entregou seus dados
   já não os entregou como texto, isso é, se são bytes, decodifica-los
   (`decode`) para que se tornem texto
3. processar seus dados
4. codifica-los novamente (`encode` )  e escreve-los na saída (se isso
   não for feito automaticamente - como acontece com arquivos de texto,
   por exemplo)

Então no seu caso, supondo-se que o objeto que você mostrou aí esteja na variável  `a`, para continuar o seu programa é só decodificar esses bytes para texto (objeto do tipo `str`)  em Python 3 e continuar seu programa:

```
a = b'N\xc3\xa3o n\xc3\xa3o n\xc3\xa3o, n\xc3\xb3s iremos sim!'
b = a.decode("utf-8")
print(b)
```

No caso, eu sei que a codificaão é utf-8 de olhar a codificação: dois bytes para um caractére acentuado, e o primeiro sendo "\xc3" é uma boa dica de que os bytes representam texto codificado em utf-8.

Uma coisa essencial para entender é a diferença entre texto (`str` em Python 3) que é composto por caractéres unicode, e bytes, que são sequências de números entre 0 e 255 efetivamente guardadas em arquivos ou trasmitidas pela rede. Para isso, não deixe de ler:

http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_(Sem_Desculpas!)

Answer (score 0):

Uma coisa ruim em *Python* é trabalhar com `string`, játive muita dor de cabeça com *unicode* e *utf-8*.

Indo ao que interessa. Em linguagens interpretadas, costuma se usar comentários de cabeçalho para "configurações" (Não fazer configuração do sistema).

Em *Python*, normalmente a primeira linha é reservada para o executável.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

ou

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

E a segunda linha costuma guardar informações de codificação:

```
#*-* coding: utf-8 *-*
#*-* coding: latin-1 *-*
```

**Use apenas um deles!**

Os trechos `*-*`, não deveriam ser necessários, mas nunca usei sem eles, então não posso dizer se vai fazer diferença.

Com essa linha, você pode usar caracteres especiais no seu código.

```
print "maçã é maçã!"
```

Caso queira usar *unicode*, pode usar o método `unicode`, para converter seus bytes.

```
uni_str = unicode("maçã", "utf-8")
```

Mas de qualquer jeito deve ter a linha de codificação obrigatoriamente em todos os arquivos!

Comment: Mas qual seria a solução para Python 3?

Comment: @ViniciusMesel. Como foi dito na resposta coloque a codificação no arquivo `#*-* coding: utf-8 *-*` na segunda linha do arquivo, independente da versão do python, com isso você irá usar os caracteres especiais normalmente

Comment: Amigo, mas o decoding não é de meu código e sim de meu arquivo que o meu código processa, como está no título da pergunta!

Comment: e amigo, unicode não funciona no Python 3!

Comment: tem como você passar o seu código e o arquivo que você tem que ler?

Comment: O processador python: https://github.com/vmesel/DataProcessing/blob/master/TwitterProcessing/dumps/proc.py e o arquivo: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9epmg4auqvwaqez/dataset.txt?dl=0

Comment: Não tem como decodificar o conteúdo desse arquivo, parece que foi escrito dessa maneiro por sacanagem, todo o conteúdo está estruturado para ser usado como string em python, o você terá que ler o arquivo e usar o `replace` para substituir as sequencias hexadecimais e as aspas

Comment: É realmente, tive que carregar um por um no Python e processá-lo, valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: Voto negativo por não saber como trabalhar com streams de bytes e texto em unicode e tentar culpar a linguagem por isso.

Comment: A propósito, o problema não tem **nada** a ver com a declaração de codificação do arquivo de código fonte que é o que muda quando se colocam as marcações do tipo `#*-* coding: utf-8 *-* ` no começo do arquivo - isso apenas indica para o parser do Python a codificação do programa em si, e não dos dados que ele trata - e em Python 3 é utf-8 por padrão (ao contrário de Python 2 em que é ASCII por padrão)